# What is C10k in web server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am read the wiki of the C10K problem but it confusing me.
Can any one explain about the following point

1. Why this problem arries
2. No of way we can solve this problem

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally, if a webserver gets a connection, it starts a worker/thread, and the worker exists until the connection is over, even if there is no or very little data going over that connection.

Since every worker needs a certain amount of RAM, the amount of workers is limited by the amount of RAM of the server, which means the number of connections is limited by RAM. Usually, you end up way below 10000 connections.

nginx, for example does not use the thread based architecture, but an event based architecture. As such it does not use a lot of resources per connection and can handle way more connections concurrently.

More info might be found in [The Architecture of Open Source Applications: nginx](http://www.aosabook.org/en/nginx.html)

Comment: RAM is just one of the issues. And the C10k problem also includes the issues with other design models. For example, if you use a big loop around `poll` or `select`, the operation gets expensive because socket discovery gets complex in the kernel/OS.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thats a good point. I linked to an article talking about the nginx architecture since it might be too much to talk about in this format.

Comment: This issue can be mitigated by horizontal scaling (more servers, i.e. have multiple hosts serving up the same resources). In my experience this issue is something that comes up when you are scaling way up in the # of client connections.  Look at using a Load Balancer or just round-robin DNS (but be aware of how they will maintain session state for your app if it's used).